# Centos 7 Failed yum install npm nodejs

Tags: node.js, centos, npm, centos7

Ставлю на centos 7 npm и nodejs, но получаю ошибку:

> ```
> --> Running transaction check
> ---> Package libicu.x86_64 0:50.1.2-15.el7 will be installed
> ---> Package libuv.x86_64 1:1.10.2-1.el7 will be installed
> ---> Package nodejs.x86_64 1:6.11.1-1.el7 will be installed
> --> Processing Dependency: http-parser >= 2.7.0 for package: 1:nodejs-6.11.1-1.el7.x86_64
> --> Processing Dependency: libhttp_parser.so.2()(64bit) for package: 1:nodejs-6.11.1-1.el7.x86_64
> --> Finished Dependency Resolution
> Error: Package: 1:nodejs-6.11.1-1.el7.x86_64 (epel)
>            Requires: libhttp_parser.so.2()(64bit)
> Error: Package: 1:nodejs-6.11.1-1.el7.x86_64 (epel)
>            Requires: http-parser >= 2.7.0
>  You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
>  You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
> ```

Попробовал поставить http-parser, но его нет в базовых репозиториях и в epel-release.

Разбирался, как исправить. Два рабочих решения -- ниже (самоответ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариантов исправления два, оба рабочие (откатывал виртуалки к контрольным точкам).

Вариант 1. Поставить пакет из rpm:

```
rpm -ivh https://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org//packages/http-parser/2.7.1/3.el7/x86_64/http-parser-2.7.1-3.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

После этого можно ставить npm и ноду.

Вариант 2. В Centos 7 штатно идёт репозиторий CR (Continious Release), в котором можно найти более старые версии библиотек. Ставим одну конкретную библиотеку из этого репозитория:

```
yum --enablerepo=cr install http-parser
```

После этого npm и nodejs также поставится без ошибки, указанной в вопросе.

Ссылки по теме:

- [Багрепорт в трекере центоса](https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=13669&nbn=8) -- указаны оба способа, оба работают
- [Багрепорт на github'е nodejs](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/5701) - указан ещё один способ, но он уже не работает (`yum install http-parser.x86_64`), добавил туда свои версии решения.
- [Похожая проблема на serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/611791/centos-7-cant-yum-install-npm), но варианты мне не подошли